# Add a field copying data from another fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with documents like the following:

```
[
    {
        "field1": "foo",
        "field2": "bar"
    },
    ...
]
```

Basically what I need is to add a field `field3` to every document with `field1` and `field2` concatenated and separated by a semicolon, like this:

```
[
    {
        "field1": "foo",
        "field2": "bar",
        "field3": "foo;bar"
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there any way to add the new column to all my documents copying values from the other fields automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For 1.x versions up vote, Use [Update by query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)  plugin and
- For versions greater than 2.3,Use [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) provided by elasticsearch.

Use following query then:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_update_by_query
{
"query": {
  "match_all": {}
},
"script": "ctx._source.field3 = ctx._source.field1 + ';' + ctx._source.field2"
}
```

Make sure to enable `scripting` in `elasticsearch.yml` and restart ES.

**This requires no reindexing**

Hope this works for you.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I've just edited your answer to add the new syntax for inline scripts. Thank you!

Comment: @stefanobaldo how do we copy data to a nested field? like to field Request.field3?  I have posted same query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607350/renaming-fields-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Hello! If I want to create a field4( with type date) from field1(of type string) ,then what would be the script like ??Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The latest (6.7) ElasticSearch supports `copy_to` in `mapping`. It doesn't say anything about adding delimiters but you can try if it allows that. If it does, that will be neat. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use `curl` to create a new field in json.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/your-index/_update_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {"match_all": {}
         },
"script": "ctx._source.newfield = ctx._source.data_field1 + ';' + ctx._source.data_field2"
}
'
```