# Renaming fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document like this

```
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "field1": "data1",
      "field2": "data2"
    }
}
```

I need to change the `field2` to `Request.field3`

```
{
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "field1": "data1",
      "Request": {
        "field3": "data2"
      }
    }
}
```

For this, first added a field mapping to existing index

```
PUT testindex/_mapping/logs
{
    "properties": 
    { 
        "Request": 
        {
            "properties": 
            {
                "field3" : 
                {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }   
    }  
}
```

Then tried reindexing

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "testindex"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "testindex1"
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.Request.field3 = ctx._source.remove(\"field2\")"
    }
}
```

Error is

```
"reason": "failed to run inline script [ctx._source.Request.field3 = ctx._source.remove(\"field2\")] using lang [groovy]",
"caused_by": {
    "type": "null_pointer_exception",
    "reason": "Cannot set property 'field3' on null object"
}
```

Comment: thanks @saeed-zhiany for formatting..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Request` field does not yet exist in your documents, so your script needs to create it first:

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "testindex"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "testindex1"
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.Request = [:]; ctx._source.Request.field3 = ctx._source.remove(\"field2\") ]"
    }
}
```

Or a bit shorter like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "testindex"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "testindex1"
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.Request = [field3: ctx._source.remove(\"field2\") ]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything more needed?

Comment: Nope. Thanks Val!

Comment: There's an error in your code - on ES 5.5 second one doesn't work and the first one has an extra bracket at the end of the script

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to **rename** the **field name** is to use the **_update_by_query** API:

Example:
**POST** http://localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_update_by_query

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "NEW_FIELD_NAME"
            }
        }
    }
  },
  "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.NEW_FIELD_NAME = ctx._source.OLD_FIELD_NAME; ctx._source.remove(\"OLD_FIELD_NAME\");"
  }
}
```