# Renaming fields to new index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with this mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/origindex/_mapping/page' -d '
   {
    "page" : {
        "properties" : {
            "title" : {"type" : "text"},
            "body" : {"type" : "text"},
            "other": {"type": "text"}
        }
     }
   }'
```

In a new index, I want to copy "title" to "title1" and "title2", and "body" to "body1" and "body2" (disregarding "other"), and change the type from "page" to "articles_eng".  The new index has this mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/newindex/_mapping/articles_eng' -d '                             
{                                                                                                  
    "articles_eng" : {                                                                             
        "properties" : {                                                                           
            "title1" : {                                                                     
                 "type" : "text",                                                                  
                 "analyzer" : "my_analyzer1"                                                    
             },                                                                                     
            "title2" : {                                                                   
                 "type" : "text",                                                                  
                 "analyzer": "my_analyzer2"                                                    
             },                                                                                     
            "body1": {                                                                       
                "type" : "text",                                                                  
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer1"                                                     
            },                                                                                     
            "body2" : {                                                                     
                "type" : "text",                                                                  
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer2" 
            }                                                   
        }                                                                                      
    }                                                                                          
}'
```

From looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607350/renaming-fields-in-elasticsearch) and the [Elasticsearch reindex docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) I come up with something like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_reindex -d '{                                                   
    "source": {                                                                                    
        "index": "origindex",                                                                          
        "type": "page",                                                                            
        "query": {                                                                                 
           "match_all": {}                                                                         
        },                                                                                         
        "_source": [ "title", "body" ]                                                             
    },                                                                                             
    "dest": {                                                                                      
        "index": "newindex"                                                                        
    },                                                                                             
    "script": {                                                                                    
        "inline": "ctx._type = \"articles_eng\"";                                                  
                  "ctx._title1 = ctx._source._title";                                         
                  "ctx._title2 = ctx._source._title";                                       
                  "ctx._body1 = ctx._source._body";                                          
                  "ctx._body2 = ctx._source._body"                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                              
}'
```

I'm having trouble with the script lines.  If I do only the top line (changing the document type), everything works fine.  If I add the rest of the lines, I get an error

> "[reindex] failed to parse field [script]"

caused by

> "Unexpected character (';' (code 59)): was expecting comma to separate
>   Object entries\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@37649463; line:
>   14, column: 50]"

Even if I can sort out the issue with the multiple statements, putting in just the second line gives me the error

> "Invalid fields added to context [title1]"}]

Can anyone help me out?  It seems like this shouldn't be impossible to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I do only the top line (changing the document type), everything
>   works fine. If I add the rest of the lines, I get an error

You don't need to put all inline statement in double quotes instead you can put all inline script statements seperated by semi-colon(`;`) and enclosed in double quotes(`"`) as shown below:

```
"script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.title1 = ctx._source.title; ctx._source.title2 = ctx._source.remove(\"title\");ctx._source.body1 = ctx._source.body; ctx._source.body2 = ctx._source.remove(\"body\");ctx._type=\"articles_eng\""
}
```

> Even if I can sort out the issue with the multiple statements, putting
>   in just the second line gives me the error

You are trying to access source fields in wrong way. Metadata fields(like `_id, _type, _index ..`) should be accessed as `ctx._type` / `ctx._id` where as source fields(like `title, body, other` in your case) should be accessed as `ctx._source.title`/ `ctx._source.body` .

So finally, your ReIndex query should look like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "origindex",
    "_source": [ "title", "body" ]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "newindex"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.title1 = ctx._source.title; ctx._source.title2 = ctx._source.remove(\"title\");ctx._source.body1 = ctx._source.body; ctx._source.body2 = ctx._source.remove(\"body\");ctx._type=\"articles_eng\""
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @avr!  This almost worked except that my "title1" and "body1" fields were always null.  I ended up doing "ctx._source.title1 = ctx._source.remove(\"title\"); ctx._source.title2 = ctx._source.title1" etc. and now all is well.  I am so grateful for your help!

Comment: I was getting values for all the fields in `newindex`. Did you see any errors while ReIndexing the data?

Comment: No, I did not.  Could it be an ES version issue?  I am using 5.0.2.

Comment: I've also run on same major version `5.2.0` . For debugging purpose, can you replace `inline` line in above code with following line `"inline": "ctx._source.title1 = ctx._source.title; ctx._source.title2 = ctx._source.title; ctx._source.body1 = ctx._source.body; ctx._source.body2 = ctx._source.body; ctx._type=\"articles_eng\""` and run the api?

Comment: That did work, although the original "title" and "body" fields are in the new index, as expected.

Comment: It's strange that why didn't previous one work! Probably, you need to eliminate them in next iteration of re-indexing for time being!

Comment: How can we write if column name more then one word ( like "title name")  in-place of title1 in the above your query?    "inline": "ctx._source.title name = ctx._source.title;